# docker routing no iptables

Tags: docker, routes, iptables, nat

I have a docker nginx image running with the command
`sudo docker run -p 8002:80 nginx`

What I am wondering is how does the routing work to go from hostmachine:8002 to get to the container listening on port 80.  Usually there are iptables that very explicitly do that, but if you disable iptables it still works.  Then I noticed that there is a `docker-proxy` process listening on each exposed port that I would assume does the proxy/nat.  So I disabled the userland proxy with `--userland-proxy=false`. After doing that I now only see one process `docker-current`, still listening on all exposed ports.  I can only assume that the `docker-current` process is doing the nat, but that makes me wondering why the userland proxy and/or iptables are ever there? And is there a way that I can see/prove to myself where the nating is happening (ie turn something on/off and not be able to curl my nginx container and then be able to)?

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness I will answer my own questions.

1. The iptables rules are there to hopefully save time by nat'ing in kernel space rather than sending it up to userspace to do the nat'ing. You can kill the process that is listening on the port and remove the iptables nat rules and not get a response from the traffic, which is how I (among other tests) was able to prove to myself what was going on.